# Research in Coding Theory

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory, encoding

I have just started learning about coding theory. Hence, I would like to ask for your suggestions and guidance for a very beginner like me.

1. Which books are good for beginning coding theory? (I start reading the notes by J.I. Hall
   from [here](http://www.mth.msu.edu/~jhall/classes/codenotes/coding-notes.html)).
2. Which topics now are hot in coding theory? so that I could look at and choose the track to follow.
3. Where I could find lastest preprints and papers on coding theory. I know only "[Designs, Codes and Cryptography](http://link.springer.com/journal/10623)".

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which aspect of coding theory you want? Engineering, Mathematics or Computer Science?

Comment: alas asking about "hot research" is not gonna make any friends around here, however coincidentally RJLipton was just blogging about the [intersection of coding theory & number theory](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/codes-meet-numbers/) specifically density of primes etc which is showing some recent attn/innovation. lots of leading refs there

Answer (score 9):

From a mathematical perspective: Try

> 1) Handbook of coding theory - Huffman and Pless
>
> 2) Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes - Huffman and Pless
>
> 3) Introduction to coding theory - Ron Roth
>
> 4) Algebraic Geometric Codes: Basic Notions - Vladut, Nogin and Tsfasman
>
> 5) Introduction to Coding Theory - Van Lint
>
> 6) Algebraic Geometry in Coding Theory and Cryptography - Harald Niederreiter and Chaoping Xing.

From an engineering perspective: Try

> 1) Error Control Coding - Shu Lin and Daniel Costello
>
> 2) Modern Coding Theory - Richardson and Urbanke
>
> 3) Error Correction Coding - Todd K Moon
>
> 4) Channel Codes: Classical and Modern - William Ryan and Shu Lin.

From Computer Science perspective: Try

> 1) Madhu Sudan MIT Notes
>
> 2) Algorithmic Results in List Decoding -  Guruswami
>
> 3) Computational complexity - Boaz Barak (Chapter 19)
>
> 4) Refer this cstheory question - [Using error-correcting codes in theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/121/using-error-correcting-codes-in-theory?rq=1)
>
> 5) Locally Decodable Codes - Yekhanin
>
> 6) Chapter on applications of coding theory in complexity theory in Different Aspects of Coding Theory - Calderbank.

Answer (score 4):

Lecture notes of the course "An Algorithmic Introduction to Coding Theory," by Madhu Sudan.
Publication Date: 2001. The first chapter offers useful comments regarding several textbooks on coding theory.
Available at http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/FT01/scribe/overall.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

My favorites for the first part of your question:

Neal Koblitz: "A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography"
$\rightarrow$ Very good introduction for mathematical treatment

Oded Goldreich: "The Foundations of Cryptography"
$\rightarrow$ More applications, but also a good book for basical interests

Thomas M. Cover and Joy A. Thomas: "Elements of Information Theory"
$\rightarrow$  This book presents a great overview about the whole package of information theory

Imre Csiszár and János Körner: "Information Theory: Coding Theorems for Discrete Memoryless Systems"
$\rightarrow$ Anonther classic for information theory

Jörg Rothe: "Complexity theory and cryptology"
$\rightarrow$ This book focussing on the complexity aspects (like the name already says)

Comment: How does Koblitz and Goldreich books contribute to starting coding theory? I don't know about others, but I studied these books and I strongly believe there's no correlation between them and beginning coding theory.

Comment: I would think Danny has suggested some books for beginners in both cryptography and Information Theory. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.^^

Comment: These are indeed very nice books to study if you are working on Cryptography, however, for topics in coding theory I am just not too sure about the first two books (having read them), why not ALSO take a look at notes from course offerings from Venkat Guruswami (CMU) or Atri Rudra (UBuffalo).

Comment: Maybe i overestimate the relevance of cryptography in this question.. :)

Answer (score 2):

excellent 50p survey by leading expert/member [Luca Trevisan](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1069/luca-trevisan) from 2004 also tracking recent/latest research in the field

- [Some Applications of Coding Theory in Computational
  Complexity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0409044v1.pdf)

sections:

> 1. Introduction
> 2. Error-Correcting codes
> 3. Sublinear Time Unique Decoding
> 4. Sublinear Time List Decoding
> 5. Locally Testable Codes